# Must-have Parachain pallets

Tags: parachain, substrate-parachain-template

Which are the absolute must-have pallets that need to be added to a runtime to make it parachain-compatible?

I am looking at the [parachain template](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/master/cumulus/parachain-template/runtime/src/lib.rs).

Are the [XCM helpers](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/master/cumulus/parachain-template/runtime/src/lib.rs#L516) necessary?

Answer (score 1):

The essential ones are:

- frame_system
- cumulus_pallet_parachain_system
- pallet_timestamp
- pallet_authorship
- pallet_collator_selection
- pallet_session
- pallet_aura
- cumulus_pallet_xcm: This pallet enables communication between your parachain and the Relay Chain using XCM. It is essential for parachain interoperability and cannot be removed.

You can make do with the other ones depending on your specific use-case by implementing custom pallets.

Comment: Can `cumulus-pallet-aura-ext` be skipped, as I see that it passes a `ConsensusHook` to `cumulus-pallet-parachain-system` and `execute_block` for `validate_block` runtime function?

Comment: Yes, you can delete it if you're using an alternative consensus mechanism like GRANDPA

Comment: Thanks.
Isn't `pallet-xcm` necessary as well? I see that `cumulus-pallet-xcm` expects an [xcm executor](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/master/cumulus/pallets/xcm/src/lib.rs#L45).